# Continuity and Directional Derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Does every absolutely continuous function on a compact set possess a left and right hand derivative everywhere on its interior? Although the two need not be equal of course.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider a function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is equal to zero except for narrow triangular peaks of height $2^{-n}$ at the point $x_n=2^{-n}$, $n=1,2,\dots$. It does not have a right-hand derivative $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very new to the ways of real analysis so I am just going to gather some intuition here. I can see it does not have a right derivative at zero. It is continuous because there are no gaps and the triangles don't have vertical sides. It has bounded variation because you have defined the triangle heights and bases using a convergent geometric progression. Therefore we can prove absolute continuity. Or am I very confused.

Comment: Clarification the link to bounded variation is superfluous. You would just proving absolute continuity using its definition. However, bounded variation is a property of a physical system or financial market which as an applied guy makes more sense to me.

Comment: minor corollary: if we constructed an analagous pattern of triangles along the negative horizontal axis we would find there was no left hand derivative at 0 either. So absolute continuity does not ensure existence of either left or right hand derivatives everywhere even though derivatives will exist almost everywhere of course. Thanks again.